# How to get the definition for a view only accessable via synonym in an Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, view, synonym

Is there any way to get the type or general table/view definition from an Oracle database synonym? Are special rights neccessary to get it or is it even impossible and I have to check the real source database?
I am especially interested in the column datatypes and length of the type (where it matters).

Thanks a lot in davance.

Comment: It depends... are you able to query the view/table _without_ the synonym?

Comment: SQL*Plus command DESC[RIBE] works with synonyms.  What more information do you need?

Comment: Ben, no not at the moment. Thanks APC, yes these are the informations I needed. If you like to write this as answer, I will close the question with that.